# PyQt: How to set ComboBox current item Wihtout knowing Item's Index Number

Tags: python, search, pyqt, qcombobox

Created **myComboBox** with:

```
myComboBox = QtGui.QComboBox()
```

Populated it with three items:

myItemsList = ['item01', 'item02', 'item03']

```
for item in myItemsList:
    myComboBox.addItem(item)
```

Now I want to set a comboBox to a second item knowing only string value of the item: ***'item02'***.

Let's assume I can't index myItemsList to find out what indexed position of an item with a value ***'item02'***.

I want to set a myComboBox without using an item index number but its string value. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [QComboBox.findText](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qcombobox.html#findText):

```
    index = myComboBox.findText('item02')
```